# How can I export to a pdf file in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to make an application that exports a PDF file whose content comes from the database. This my controller controller:

```
 public ActionResult DownloadTopic(int Id)
    { 
        var Topic = DB.Topics.singleordefualt(o=>o.id == Id);

        return File(Topic.Body, "application/pdf");
    }
```

But I get this error `"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\katkooot\Desktop\project\Discussion\MvcApplication22\MvcApplication22\Topic\DownloadTopic"`.

Comment: What Type is Body? Stream? String (Path to file)?

Comment: Is `DownloadTopic` the name of the file?  If so, it's missing the `.pdf` extension.

Comment: Does the file exist on the server in that directory?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist , i want to create the pdf file and put the content of the body field in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the result into PDF. You cannot just take the result that is some .NET class, interface or custom user object and return it as PDF just like that. You should use libraries like [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to enumerate through your results and return a PDF. Here is a tutorial by Ozzie Perez on how to open a document, write a PDF table and return it to the user [Creating a PDF with iTextSharp and ASP.Net MVC 2](http://ozzieperez.net/blog/?p=255)

Comment: thank you for your help :) i am still beginner so i am very sorry if the details wasn't enough . but you really help me

Comment: Don't worry about it. If you need some more help just shout. :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough details, it would greatly help if you would answer what others asked - what is the type of `Topic`.

But based on this as a wild guess - try to return `FileContent` instead of `File`.